# Succinct way of stating that two inequalities always have the same direction

Tags: inequality, notation, relations

Is there a succinct yet still clear way to state the following?

- $a > b$ if and only if $c > d$; $a = b$ if and only if $c = d$; and $a < b$ if and only if $c < d$.

One succinct way could be

- $a > $ (or $=$,$<$) $ b$ if and only if $c >$ (or $=$,$<$) $ d$.

but I am a bit concerned that it may confuse some readers.

Comment: One potential way to put it could be $\text{sign}(a - b) = \text{sign}(c - d).$

Comment: For each $R\in\{>,=,<\}$, $a\mathrel{R}b$ iff $c\mathrel{R}d$.

Comment: If you just spelled it out as in after the indented bullet, it would not confuse a reader,